# Add IP Routes and Rules at Startup

Tags: linux, networking, route, startup

I’m currently routing some marked packets via `eth0`. However, I have to apply the routing rules every time the system reboots. The two commands I always have to re enter are

```
ip rule add fwmark 3 table 3
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 3
```

The gateway for `eth0` being `192.168.0.1` I’ve tried placing those commands in both `/etc/rc.local` and `/etc/network/interfaces`, and in both cases I have still had to run them manually. Does anyone have a suggestion as to where/how to run these commands on every startup?

Comment: Which distribution and version are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `/etc/network/interfaces` file only.

You just have to put your `add route` command under the desired interface and put `post-up` or `pre-down` keywords before that command.

`post-up` keyword will add that route in the routing table after you will have brought up that interface and `pre-down` keyword will remove it before you will have brought down that interface.

For example:
To add static route on `eth0` interface, `/etc/network/interfaces` file should be

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    ...
    ...
    post-up ip route replace default via 192.168.0.1
    pre-down ip route delete default via 192.168.0.1 || true
```

Comment: Turned out that OpenVPN was messing with commands I placed in there, so I kept the marking rule in the interfaces file, but moved the route adding to a file that runs on OpenVPN start up. Marking this as correct, since if it weren't for OpenVPN it would've worked.

Answer (score 6):

Put your commands in a shell script e.g. /usr/local/sbin/myrouting and make it executable.

You could use cron and an @reboot target in /etc/crontab or the root crontab e.g. /etc/crontab

```
@reboot root /usr/local/sbin/myrouting
```

or root crontab

```
@reboot /usr/local/sbin/myrouting
```

You could also do it using systemd.

Create a systemd unit file /etc/systemd/system/myrouting.service

```
[Unit]
after=network

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/myrouting

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then enable it

```
systemctl enable myrouying.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/myrouting.service → /etc/systemd/system/myrouting.service.
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also add these command into /etc/rc.local and don't forget to make it executable:

```
touch stagingfile.txt

echo "ip rule add fwmark 3 table 3" >> stagingfile.txt
echo "ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 3" >> stagingfile.txt

sudo mv stagingfile.txt /etc/rc.local
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

should work